# Android SDK and AVD managers stop working after I download new packages

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-manager

Everything worked fine right after I installed Android SDK. I downloaded various packages and was informed that the download was successful and that the packages have been installed. The next time I try to run either SDK manager or AVD manager, nothing will happen other than a brief CMD window that would flash for a second before disappearing.

I tried reinstalling Android from scratch and got exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem (Windows 7 x64) - The issue appears to be that tools/lib/findjava.bat has changed in r17, and no longer seems to be able to locate the 64bit version of the JDK.

Installing the 32bit version of the JDK seems to have fixed it.